# Detect the use of a VPN connection _to_ a box by traffic coming _from_ the box

Tags: ip, vpn

Imagine that we have three boxes:

```
A <--(VPN)--> B <--(public internet)--> C
```

A and B are connected via a VPN. B and C are connected via the public internet.

Let's assume that A and B run Windows.

Is it possible for an observer on C to somehow detect if the IP packets reaching it from B originated not on B but on A?

One obvious clue would be packets' TTL. Let's assume that A can increment the TTL of the outgoing packets to compensate for the extra hop.

I suppose that the IP packet that reaches C has no traces of the A's IP address, and looks emitted entirely by B. Is this correct?

Comment: If A and B run Windows, then they are off-topic hosts/servers/VMs. Also, you have not given enough detail, such as the addressing, but we cannot answer about anything your hosts are doing. You could ask about that on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for an observer on C to somehow detect if the IP packets reaching it from B originated not on B but on A?

No. Assuming there's private IPv4 addressing between A and B, B needs to NAT its own and A's addresses alike when forwarding to/accessing the public Internet.

The TTL isn't really a giveaway since it could be caused by any routed hop before B - LAN or VPN doesn't matter. Also, B could reset the TTL counter to hide any of that.

There may be other clues for C on higher protocol layers (eg. an HTTP agent), especially when no effective transport encryption is used, but protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off topic here.